# How to integrate android native code with Qt Quick project?

Tags: android, qt, wifi, qtandroidextras, qandroidjniobject

I am trying to get wifi name connected to my mobile using QAndroidJniObject.

> java file:

```
package org.qtproject.example;
import android.net.NetworkInfo.DetailedState;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;



public class QtAndroidToastJava extends QtActivity
{



    public static String getWifiName(Context context) {
        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (manager.isWifiEnabled()) {
           WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
           if (wifiInfo != null) {
              DetailedState state = WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState());
              if (state == DetailedState.CONNECTED || state == DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR) {
                  return wifiInfo.getSSID();
              }
           }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My cpp code is

```
void WIFICLASS::updateAndroidNotification()
{

qDebug()<<"******************************************8";

auto returnString = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod <jstring>("org/qtproject/example/QtAndroidToastJava",
                                             "getWifiName","(V;)Ljava/lang/String");

// //  QString user = juser.toString();
//   qDebug()<<"ANSWER"<<user;

 qDebug()<<returnString;

}
```

After trying to build this I am getting this errors:
**23: error: undefined reference to '_jstring* QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<_jstring*>(char const*, char const*, char const*, ...)**'

How can I solve this issue?

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you add `QT += androidextras` to the .pro file?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I have added QT += androidextras
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android in my pro file

Comment: By adding this line `QAndroidJniObject returnString = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/example/QtAndroidToastJava","getWifiName","(Landroid/content/Context)",QtAndroid::androidContext().object());**` I am getting error: **"W System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Lorg/qtproject/example/QtAndroidToastJava;.getWifiName(Landroid/content/Context)""** I think I need proper arguments for context as I am using context **getWifiName(Context context)** as parameter to my function in java@FrankOsterfeld what should I add in place of(Landroid/content/Context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong here:

1.) The message signature you are passing in C++ is wrong. It should be:

```
"(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;"
```

Mind the `;` at the end of each class name! It is always `L<classname>;`! Also, you have to always exactly match the method as declared in java. Multiple parameters do not need to be seperated. If you have e.g. a method `void test(int a, int b)`, the signature would be `(II)V`.

2.) The method you are calling is an object method, which means you must use `QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod`

```
auto res = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/example/QtAndroidToastJava",
                                                     "getWifiName",
                                                     "(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;",
                                                     QtAndroid::androidContext().object());
```

That method returns you an `QAndroidJniObject` and you can call `QAndroidJniObject::toString()` to convert the result to a string.

Comment: In that case you should accept/upvote the answer, so other people can see that this solved the problem.